# Не работают copy-paste-cat в Русской раскладке linux mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, hotkeys, atom

Перестали работать Ctrl+c и Ctrl+V в редакторе Atom. В системе работают они в браузере, в терминале и тд при любой раскладке. Система Linux Mint. После перезагрузки горячие клавиши работают и в Atome, но при английской раскладке. Сталкивался ли кто? В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: а может они перестают работать, когда включена не английская раскладка клавиатуры?

Comment: @KoVadim не работает именно в атоме, при любой раскладке клавиатуры, перезагрузка атома лечит эту проблему на 40-50 минут, потом снова перестает работать...(

Comment: надо искать, что приводит к этому. Может быть какое-то спец нажатие или плугин.

Comment: @KoVadim вроде не нажимаю ничего, да и раньше такой проблемы не было, наверн плагин какой нибудь, я вчера понаставил. Спасибо! Поковыряю плагины

Comment: @KoVadim вы правы, посмотрел по разным раскладкам кла-вы, не работают copy-cat-paste в атоме только в русской раскладке.. вы сталкивались с такой проблемой?

Comment: я такое встрачал в старых дистрибутивах (но не в атоме:) его тогда не было). Проверил прямо сейчас - да. сломано:) Пишите в поддержку атома.

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо!)